# How do I add a Fragment to an Activity with a programmatically created content view

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-fragments

I want to add a Fragment to an Activity that implements its layout programmatically. I looked over the Fragment documentation but there aren't many examples describing what I need. Here is the type of code I tried to write:

```
public class DebugExampleTwo extends Activity {

    private ExampleTwoFragment mFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(this);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            mFragment = new ExampleTwoFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.add(frame.getId(), mFragment).commit();
        }

        setContentView(frame);
    }
}
```

...

```
public class ExampleTwoFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
                             ViewGroup container, 
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Button button = new Button(getActivity());
        button.setText("Hello There");
        return button;
    }
}
```

This code compiles but crashes at start, probably because my `FragmentTransaction.add()` is incorrect. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: (2022) often you wanna simply add them: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72677537/294884

Answer (score 209, accepted):

It turns out there's more than one problem with that code. A fragment cannot be declared that way, inside the same java file as the activity but not as a public inner class. The framework expects the fragment's constructor (with no parameters) to be public and visible. Moving the fragment into the Activity as an inner class, or creating a new java file for the fragment fixes that.

The second issue is that when you're adding a fragment this way, you must pass a reference to the fragment's containing view, and that view must have a custom id. Using the default id will crash the app. Here's the updated code:

```
public class DebugExampleTwo extends Activity {

    private static final int CONTENT_VIEW_ID = 10101010;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(this);
        frame.setId(CONTENT_VIEW_ID);
        setContentView(frame, new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Fragment newFragment = new DebugExampleTwoFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.add(CONTENT_VIEW_ID, newFragment).commit();
        }
    }

    public static class DebugExampleTwoFragment extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            EditText v = new EditText(getActivity());
            v.setText("Hello Fragment!");
            return v;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you only want to use the fragment as the top level content view of the activity, then you can use `ft.add(android.R.id.content, newFragment)`. It's only necessary to create a custom layout and setting its id if the fragment's container is not the activity's content view.

Comment: Instead of hard coding the id, you can [define it in XML](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Id) and reference it as normal (R.id.myid).

Comment: @JasonHanley if I will be creating many views, do you know how I will generate many unique view id's programmatically?

Comment: I don't know how to do that, but remember that an id only has to be unique in the scope that you need to use it.

Comment: the id only needs to be unique in its level within the current heirarchy of the containing layout. So say its wrapped in a linear layout, it only needs to be unqiue among the other views within that linear layout.

Comment: @TonyWong to create a uniqID its easiest to have a private member of the class DebugExampleTwoFragment that is static and an int. Overload the constructor to first call super() then increment that counter.

Comment: @TonyWong Is it possible to get same behaviour of TabViewActivity using fragmentation, I want to open a new activity in fragmentation area if I select any of tab?

Comment: Tony, are you sure about that regarding `android.R.id.content`? From the doc (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add(int%2C%20android.app.Fragment)), only this is specified: "Optional identifier of the container this fragment is to be placed in. If 0, it will not be placed in a container.". I don't see where this `android.R.id.content` is coming from...

Comment: @RedGlyph It's been a while, but I think I got `android.R.id.content` by looking at the Android source code. I seem to recall it's the default id they use in a couple of places.

Comment: You can create an ID dynamically using setId(View.NO_ID) and then getId() to see what it was.

Comment: When, in the answer, you say "custom id", are you excluding the `generateViewID` method? I have a crash because it does not find the view with a generated ID. Trying to understand more...

Comment: @AntonioSesto I couldn't use `generateViewID` because it's only available in API 17 and newer. When I wrote the question only API 11 was available.

Comment: @TonyWong Thank you, but I cannot see how this solution is different from mine. In this solution you have a single ID, in my case I have several of them generated by View.generateID() - which usually starts from 1.

Answer (score 76):

Here is what I came up with after reading [Tony Wong's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159982/how-do-i-add-a-fragment-to-an-activity-with-a-programmatically-created-content-v#comment5796720_5161143):

```
public class DebugExampleTwo extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addFragment(android.R.id.content,
                    new DebugExampleTwoFragment(),
                    DebugExampleTwoFragment.FRAGMENT_TAG);
    }

}
```

...

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    protected void addFragment(@IdRes int containerViewId,
                               @NonNull Fragment fragment,
                               @NonNull String fragmentTag) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(containerViewId, fragment, fragmentTag)
                .disallowAddToBackStack()
                .commit();
    }

    protected void replaceFragment(@IdRes int containerViewId,
                                   @NonNull Fragment fragment,
                                   @NonNull String fragmentTag,
                                   @Nullable String backStackStateName) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(containerViewId, fragment, fragmentTag)
                .addToBackStack(backStackStateName)
                .commit();
    }

}
```

...

```
public class DebugExampleTwoFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String FRAGMENT_TAG = 
        BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".DEBUG_EXAMPLE_TWO_FRAGMENT_TAG";

    // ...

}
```

## Kotlin

If you are using Kotlin make sure to take a look at what the [Kotlin extensions](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx) by Google provide or just write your own.

Comment: Don't do so! Check `if (savedInstanceState == null)` before fragment creation, or after rotating a screen you will have two fragments or fragments reordering. Do not use `add` method at all! Only `replace`. Or you will have weird behaviour.

Comment: Where do you get the value for "backStackStateName"? (When using the replace function)

Comment: @vikzilla You can find pretty good answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984950/what-is-the-meaning-of-addtobackstack-with-null-parameter) and in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction#addToBackStack(java.lang.String)). In short: the `backStackStateName` string is something which is defined by you.

Answer (score 37):

```
    public class Example1 extends FragmentActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          DemoFragment fragmentDemo = (DemoFragment) 
          getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container);
          //above part is to determine which fragment is in your frame_container
          setFragment(fragmentDemo);
                       (OR)
          setFragment(new TestFragment1());
        }

        // This could be moved into an abstract BaseActivity 
        // class for being re-used by several instances
        protected void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }
```

> To add a fragment into a Activity or FramentActivity it requires a
>   Container. That container should be a "`Framelayout`", which can be
>   included in xml or else you can use the default container for that
>   like "`android.R.id.content`" to remove or replace a fragment in
>   Activity.

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
 <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
   <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagenext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/next" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 33):

After read all Answers I came up with elegant way:

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

 Fragment fragment ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag("myFragmentTag");
    if (fragment == null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragment =new MyFragment();
        ft.add(android.R.id.content,fragment,"myFragmentTag");
        ft.commit();
    }

}
```

basically you don't need to add a frameLayout as container of your fragment instead you can add straight the fragment into the android  root View container

IMPORTANT: **don't use replace fragment** as most of the approach shown here, unless you don't mind to lose fragment variable instance state during **onrecreation** process.

Comment: thanks for the answer, this adds the fragment tab to the whole screen? but how you add to one frame layout or view pager?

Answer (score 9):

For attaching fragment to an activity programmatically in Kotlin, you can look at the following code:

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

            // create fragment instance
            val fragment : FragmentName = FragmentName.newInstance()

            // for passing data to fragment
            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putString("data_to_be_passed", DATA)
            fragment.arguments = bundle

            // check is important to prevent activity from attaching the fragment if already its attached
            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                supportFragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, "fragment_name")
                    .commit()
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**FragmentName.kt**

```
class FragmentName : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = FragmentName()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        // receiving the data passed from activity here
        val data = arguments!!.getString("data_to_be_passed")
        return view
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    }

}
```

If you are familiar with [Extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) in Kotlin then you can even better this code by following [this](https://medium.com/thoughts-overflow/how-to-add-a-fragment-in-kotlin-way-73203c5a450b) article.

Answer (score 6):

```
public abstract class SingleFragmentActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String FRAGMENT_TAG = "single";
    private Fragment fragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            fragment = onCreateFragment();
           getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                   .add(android.R.id.content, fragment, FRAGMENT_TAG)
                   .commit();
       } else {
           fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG);
       }
   }

   public abstract Fragment onCreateFragment();

   public Fragment getFragment() {
       return fragment;
   }

}
```

use

```
public class ViewCatalogItemActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity {
    @Override
    public Fragment onCreateFragment() {
        return new FragmentWorkShops();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

For **API level 17** or higher, [`View.generateViewId()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#generateViewId%28%29) will solve this problem. The utility method provides a unique id that is not used in build time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 5):

This may help you

**Defining a Fragment**

create xml file for fragment view fragment_abc.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

create fragment ABCFragment.java

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class FooFragment extends Fragment {
// The onCreateView method is called when Fragment should create its View object hierarchy,
// either dynamically or via XML layout inflation. 

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle 
savedInstanceState) {
    // Defines the xml file for the fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_abc, parent, false);
}

// This event is triggered soon after onCreateView().
// Any view setup should occur here.  E.g., view lookups and attaching view listeners.
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Setup any handles to view objects here
    // EditText etFoo = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etFoo);
}
}
```

Add frameLayout in your activity

```
<FrameLayout
   android:id="@+id/your_placeholder"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

now in activity, add following method

```
protected void setFragment() {
    // Begin the transaction
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    // Replace the contents of the container with the new fragment
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new ABCFragment());
    // or ft.add(R.id.your_placeholder, new ABCFragment());
    // Complete the changes added above
    ft.commit();
}
```

reference : https://guides.codepath.com/android/creating-and-using-fragments#defining-a-fragment