# Adding a Fragment Dynamically inside a view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have started with this [How do I add a Fragment to an Activity with a programmatically created content view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159982/how-do-i-add-a-fragment-to-an-activity-with-a-programmatically-created-content-v)

To create and add a Fragment inside an Activity.

But when i tried to add the same fragment inside a dynamic view, it failed.

Can u please address what is the problem behind it.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final int CONTENT_VIEW_ID = 10101010;
    private static final int CONTENT_VIEW_ID1 = 10101011;

    public FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        View view = new View(this);

        FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(this);
        frame.setId(CONTENT_VIEW_ID);
        frame.addView(view,new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        view.setId(CONTENT_VIEW_ID1);
        setContentView(frame);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Fragment newFragment1 = new DebugExampleTwoFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction(); 
            ft.add(CONTENT_VIEW_ID1, newFragment1);
            ft.commit();
        }

public static class DebugExampleTwoFragment extends Fragment {
        public static int count = 0;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = new View(getActivity());
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            return v;
        }
    }
```

It failed with `ClassCastException` the exact line number is not displayed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably getting message like this:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.View cannot be cast to
>   android.view.ViewGroup

That's because fragment can be inserted into `ViewGroup` or something that inherits from `ViewGroup`. You cannot insert fragment into `View`. To make your code run change this line:

```
View view = new View(this);
```

into ,for example, this:

```
FrameLayout view = new FrameLayout(this);//FrameLayout inherits from ViewGroup
```