# Animating Listview, dynamically expanding to fill screen

Tags: android, animation

Ok so I have 3 list views, my layout looks something like this

Listview 1 
Button 1 
Listview 2 
Button 2 
Listview 3 
Button 3

What I want to do is,

When the user clicks Button 1 one I want Listview 1 to fill the screen, but the animation should be similar to a garage door collapsing on top of the views below.

In addition to that when the user clicks Button 2, the 2nd listview needs to expand to fill the screen but over the other views. Right now when I run the animation it either goes out of the screen completely.

How do create a garage door like animation, basically sliding over other views and covering them up. Something like the Android status bar drag down.

Could someone tell me how to accomplish this? I tried various ways but didn't get far.

Comment: You might want to look at `Fragments`: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 0):

Convert each of the `listviews` into [`ListFragments`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html)  and then display them as usual, 
When the user clicks on a button expand the ListFragment by [adding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5161143/492561) it dynamically

Comment: I am sure you know how to implement a ListFragment since you already have a listview,
and for the sliding animation you can look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4819665/492561