# a function of android:how to use the function of "inflate(int resource, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot)"

Tags: android, layout-inflater, android-inflate

[image: Screenshot]

This image came from the official documents.But I don't understand one of the words:`"or else simply an object that provides a set of LayoutParams values for root of the returned hierarchy (if attachToRoot is false.)"`

Can you explain it for me?

Comment: Best tutorial for this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fxVeFwtIpVc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inflate is used to add a view, especially used for inflating fragments inside an activity. **ViewGroup root** is the parent view in which you want to inflate your view.
If you are using this function to inflate a fragment then use it like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_name,container,false);
    return view;
}
```

If this does not answer your query then let me know in what context are you exactly using inflate.

Comment: When the second parameter is not null and the third parameter is false,what effect   does the second parameter have?

Comment: Third parameter defines whether android should inflate the layout(i.e. first parameter) in the container(i.e. second parameter) right after inflate is called or not. It is best to keep the third parameter false irrespective of the container being null or not, and set the fragment using `FragmentManager.beginTransaction()` later on in your activity.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.I think a related qusetion.When the second parameter is not null and the third parameter is false,how  is the LayoutParams of the view inflated by the first  parameters  seted?

Comment: `view.setLayoutParams()` should work in this case. Refer this if it helps 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224433/can-i-set-layoutparams-to-fragment-by-programming

Comment: Sorry，I still  can not understand.