# Dynamically Add Fragment with LayoutParams

Tags: android, android-fragments

Is it possible to add dynamically add Fragments with LayoutParams? I have 2 fragments that I want to put in a RelativeLayout: one should lock to the left. The other should be locked to the right.

Comment: Do you absolutely need a `RelativeLayout`? This sounds like more of a job for a horizontal `LinearLayout`...

Comment: It's an example for sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* wrap them each in a layout (such as a `LinearLayout`), then set its size and position. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5161143/1438733) is regarding a similar problem, and shows how to use a `FrameLayout` with custom layout parameters to contain a `Fragment`.

Note that, when using the `fragment` object in XML, you can use `android:layout_*` attributes to control its position. Like so:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    ... >

    <fragment
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        ... />

    <fragment
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        ... />

</LinearLayout>
```

However, I don't think it's possible to apply layout parameters programmatically to [`Fragment`s](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html). They're not `ViewGroup`s, after all.

Comment: This is what I was afraid of. I'm hoping this isn't true. What a poor API choice. Google rants about not having nested unneeded layouts and now I'm forced to use nested layouts for positioning fragments. sigh....

Comment: Well, consider a `Fragment` in the same vein as an `Activity`. They perform slightly different tasks, but neither one is a layout object. They're both designed for running a portion of a process individually. To me, this is actually a good design decision; it keeps the functional code separate from the layout code.

Comment: I think I'm going to try having setLayoutParams on my fragment, and then in onCreateView add the custom layout params to the view before I return it. Still terrible I need an "id" to a container and can't use a reference....you're killing me El Goog.

Comment: How is not being able to control the composition of a layout a good thing?

Comment: You can completely control the composition of a layout. But instead of directly controlling the functional portion of the layout, you're containing it in a layout. Additionally, I just remembered (stupid of me) that `Fragment` XML objects [can have layout weights](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating) applied to them. I'm going to amend my post to reflect this, as it may be a good enough solution.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but that isn't dynamic anymore. However it's kind of like my idea above which I think will work though. Thanks for all the help and ideas. Totally appreciate it. :-)

Answer (score 6):

I used the following approach for a ListFragment in a LinearLayout:

```
class CustomListFragment
    extends ListFragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        ViewGroup v = (ViewGroup) super.onCreateView(inflater, container,
                savedInstanceState);
        v.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1));
        return v;
    }
}
```

Now that I read your comments on the other answer, I see it is similar to what you considered.

But note: the framework may instantiate your fragments. Therefore, the class must be public and must have a constructor without any further arguments.

Any setter-methods to customize your fragments won't work therefore, as they won't be called for any framework-created instances.

Comment: this works! somewhere inside android those LayoutParams are applied to the view that contains frame view.

Answer (score 1):

For specific cases, you can move the layer ordering into onStart() override

Fragment looks like this

public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

```
private Client client;

public interface Client {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams fetchFragmentOneParams(FragmentOne fragment);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    Activity activity = getActivity();

    try {
        client = (Client) getActivity();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement FragmentOne.Client");
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    getView().setLayoutParams(client.fetchFragmentOneParams(this));
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    RelativeLayout view = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
    //
    // code
    //
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set **LayoutParameters** of your Fragment in ***onCreateView*** method.
Befor returning the final view as return value of this method you can set layout parameters. As a sample below fragment return a TextView as its View which stucked to its parent left by setting LayoutParams on it:

```
    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "placeholder_text";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
                ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        LayoutParams lp  = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        textView.setLayoutParams(lp);

        return textView;
    }
}
```