# Native Child View does not occupy full height and width of FrameLayout

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, android-fragments, android-framelayout

I am trying to integrate `camera-x` inside an `android fragment` in `react-native`

Here is my native code

```
class CealScanQrView(context: Context): FrameLayout(context) {

 init {
        val frameLayoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        )
        layoutParams = frameLayoutParams
       setLayoutParams(layoutParams)
        setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#5FD3F3"))

        preview = PreviewView(context)
        preview.id = View.generateViewId()
        preview.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        )
        addView(preview)
}
//other non related code
......
}
```

Instead of `Framelayout`, I tried using `Linearlayout` and `ConstraintLayout` as well but same issue persists

on `react-native` side, I am using it as follows

```
const App = () => {
//non-related code here
.....

 return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <StatusBar barStyle={isDarkMode ? 'light-content' : 'dark-content'} />

      {isCameraPermissionGranted ? (
        <CealScanQrViewManager
          style={{
            // converts dpi to px, provide desired height
            height: PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(200),
            // converts dpi to px, provide desired width
            width: PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(200),
          }}
          ref={ref}
          onChange={readQr}
        />
      ) : (
        <View style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}} />
      )}
      <Text style={{color: 'red', fontSize: 25}}>{firstText}</Text>
      <Text style={{color: 'red', fontSize: 25}}>{secondText}</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

This is how my UI looks

[image]

You can see there is space between camera and the first text in red color.
that space is the `Framelayout` but the camera does not occupy the entire space of `Framelayout` which I don't understand why

Full source code [here](https://github.com/PritishSawant/AndroidCameraXWithFragment)

Comment: check if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12357886/dynamically-add-fragment-with-layoutparams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue with your code is that you styling it with 200x200 pixels here:

```
<CealScanQrViewManager
          style={{
            // You intentionally scale it to be small
            height: PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(200),
            width: PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(200),
          }}
```

The second thing is that you are using PreviewView from androidx camera package, which is not a simple `SurfaceView` or `TextureView` but rather a wrapper over either. What does it mean - the documentation states that

> It internally uses either a TextureView or SurfaceView to display the camera feed, and applies required transformations on them to correctly display the preview, this involves correcting their aspect ratio, scale and rotation.

That means that if will use only the correct view disregarding any warping related to the size of the preview container as it was before with Surface o Texture views. So if the preview size or aspect ratio is different from your screen(or component which parents your preview), it won't match the parent dimensions but will be scaled to look 'correctly' and inside the preview size bounds.

Channeling the camera preview inside the plain Surface or Texture views won't have this limitation, but it will be warped if the dimensions or aspect ration of your container and preview won't match.

It is not the solution, but there is no simple solution in your case - you have to consider the info above to adjust your code.

***Edit***

There is one more method, but it is tricky, and I won't give you an implementation - just a general approach. What you can do it that you can get the aspect ratio and size of your preview and cut it via negative padding or custom view container with some relevant logic in there. This is not the easy way, nor is it that hard - it is just tricky and seemingly very redundant.

For example, if your preview aspect ratio (h/w) = 1.20 and your screen aspect ratio (h/w) = 1.40, your preview will have gaps at the top and bottom if centered. Now your goal is to make the aspect ratio of the preview to be 1.40 without warping the image rendered on it - you will have to cut the preview from left and right for it not to have gaps at the top and bottom. And vice versa if your preview aspect ratio is bigger than the screens one

Something like that.

Comment: so what you're saying is I should replace my preview view with surface view, correct?

Comment: I want to stick with preview view as that is easier to implement with camerax

Comment: What if I remove the style where I am specifying the pixels, still I am not able to assign the preview view to take max height

Comment: That is the point - you won't be able to assign the preview to occupy the whole space you need if the preview itself is of a different aspect ratio - it should look much better without that limitation of yours, but yeah - basically, it is like that. The SufaceView will help you only so much(the image will be warped). But there is one more solution I've just remembered - I will add it in the edit now

Answer (score 1):

Pavlo's answer helped me but if anyone is interested in the exact answer, here is what I did

I removed the `style prop` from native side and changed `manuallyLayoutChildren` method as follows

```
  private fun manuallyLayoutChildren(view: ViewGroup) {
        for (i in 0 until view.childCount) {
            val child = view.getChildAt(i)
            child.measure(
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.measuredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.measuredHeight, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY))
            child.layout(0, 0, child.measuredWidth, child.measuredHeight)
        }

    }
```