# Issue on calling function of Fragment Class from Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-fragmentactivity

I am writing an application using `ActionBarSherlock` and `viewPagerIndicator`.

`My Aim is`:

To launch a Dialogue Activity(`AddDialogue.java`), when I am selecting menu item from `MainScrenActivity.java`. By Pressing the button in `AddDialogue.java`, it should check for network connection and display the items in `listview`.

In `AddDialogue.java` I am using the updateListview() method, which is defined in testFragment class.

AddDialogue.java:

```
public class AddDialogue extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    private static final int THEME = R.style.Theme_Sherlock_Light_Dialog;
    private Button goButton;
    private String strurl = "http://feeds.hindustantimes.com/HT-IndiaSectionPage-Topstories";
    EditText editText;
    TestFragment testFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        setTheme(THEME); // Used for theme switching in samples
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_dialogue);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
        this.goButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.go);
        this.goButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                TestFragment testFragment = new TestFragment();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ok is clicked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("dialogue", "ok is clicked");
                testFragment.updateListView(strurl);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

TestFragment.java

```
public final class TestFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String KEY_CONTENT = "TestFragment:Content";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
} 
...

public void updateListView(String strurl) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Url in updateListView : " + strurl);
        if (isOnline()) {
            animationLoadingImage.start();
            loadingImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            new RequestTask().execute(strurl);
            // openMenu(view);
        } else {
            // openMenu(view);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    "There is no network connection" + TAG, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
public boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity()
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

`My Problem is`:

I am receiving following logs, when I pressed button from activity.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 2316): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime( 2316):    at com.mistral.droidcast.TestFragment.isOnline(TestFragment.java:363)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2316):    at com.mistral.droidcast.TestFragment.updateListView(TestFragment.java:348)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2316):    at com.mistral.droidcast.AddDialogue$1.onClick(AddDialogue.java:45)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2316):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2316):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2316):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2316):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2316):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2316):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2316):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2316):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2316):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2316):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2316):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/        (  122): Dumpstate > /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
W/ActivityManager(  122):   Force finishing activity com.mistral.droidcast/.AddDialogue
```

I know that, i couldn't access any view's from TestFragment.java and missing something in my code. But, I don't know what is that.

Please help me to solve it.

Thank u in Advance!!!

Comment: cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() may return null if your phone is not connected > http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getActiveNetworkInfo()

Comment: @EvZ no, my net work is connected only. Even I take it out that network checking, the same error will be on "animationLoadingImage.start();".

Comment: @Dhasneem Did you get the solution to call fragment class method from sherlockfragmentactivity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check what happened at the line `TestFragment.isOnline(TestFragment.java:363)`

My guess is getActivity() returns null. It means that your fragment hasn't attached to your activity. You will need to add fragment to the activity as descibed here [How do I add a Fragment to an Activity with a programmatically created content view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159982/how-do-i-add-a-fragment-to-an-activity-with-a-programmatically-created-content-v)

Comment: I couldn't cal ft.add() method for my TestFragment instance? What will i do?

Comment: It is difficult to understand for do you mean without code example and logs. My assumtions are that you doesn't have containver in your activity which you try to replace with your fragment. What you should do to insert your fragment: imlpement in your layout view container, insert this layout into activity via setContentView(), than get this container and user in operation with ft.add(). For more details please see an official documentation https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html