# Android: how to show two activity in one window using java code (not using .xml)

Tags: android

How to show two activity in one window using java code(not use .xml code) in Android.

Comment: sir ,Can i use fargemet only .java file ,no use .xml file.

Comment: i doubt there are other options , not sure but fragment can help you refer tuts

Comment: I'd be very surprised if you *couldn't* create fragments in Java code. Ultimately, it's Java code that reads the xml file an lays out the application.

Answer (score 2):

You can only call one activity at a time, but you have some options for displaying more than one "process" on the screen at the same time. Fragments are a common use for this:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html
From this link - "You can combine multiple fragments in a single activity to build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple activities."

You can also use toasts to display a message or prompt, splashes for a loading screen, etc.

If you tell me more about the two activities I can give you a more specific answer.

Comment: Be careful how you use the word "process". It has a completely different meaning to how you're using it.

Comment: That's why I put quotations around it! I was having trouble finding a better word to describe what @adp is looking to do, since the question is vague. We java programmers have used a good bit of the English language to describe "stuff" and that makes it tough to find a word that doesn't have another use. Ha. =)

Comment: Yeah I get that, but of all the words to use that could give people the wrong idea. Not sure I can think of a better word but you could re-phrase your answer to say something like "you can only have one Activity but it can have multiple Fragments" (leaving out the bit about "...displaying more than one "whatever" on the screen".

Comment: sir ,Can i use fargemet only .java file ,no use .xml file.

Comment: Can i use fargemet only .java file ,no use .xml file.

Comment: Go check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159982/how-do-i-add-a-fragment-to-an-activity-with-a-programmatically-created-content-v. This will show you how to add a fragment programatically (with Java instead of XML).