# Bring fragment in android activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am creating an Android application with a bottom bar. I used an Android fragment to create the bottom bar and it is working well. Now I want to add some more activities to the application.  The problem is I can't get my bottom bar fragment in the Activity.  Is there any way to bring my fragment into an Android Activity?  I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5161143) and a lot of other examples from the Google.  Can anyone help me bring my fragments to an Activity?

Comment: why are you working with multiple activities, just work with fragments and change them in the main container

Comment: Don't start new activity on bottom bar button click, As A.S. said change only fragment in main view.

Comment: ok thank you for your feedback, i think i dot know much more about fragment working so the issue happen