# How do you connect a CustomListAdapter to a List Fragment in the Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

The context is:

1. I have an activity consisting of a fragment where there is a form to enter a date and a flight number. There are no other fragments there.
2. On click of a button, a request is made to a webservice.
3. A `List` of Flight Objects is returned from the webservice.
4. A custom `ArrayAdapter` is created for each row in the listFragment.
5. Show the results in a ListFragment in the same Activity on the frontend.

**FlightResultAdapter.java:**

```
public class FlightResultAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Flight>{
    public FlightResultAdapter(Context context, List<Flight> flights) {
        super(context, R.layout.item_flight, flights);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Flight flight = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_flight, parent, false);
        }
//Set the content of the custom row layout
        TextView tvFlightNum = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvFlightNum);
        tvFlightNum.setText(flight.getNumber());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**Note: ListFragment has a default layout that consists of a single list view.** [Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html)

So I do not need a layout file for the list.

**MyActivity.java:** A list of objects (`flightList.getFlight`) is used to create the `CustomListAdapter`. This code is inside a function that is triggered on an `OnClick`.

```
FlightResultAdapter adapter = 
new FlightResultAdapter(getApplicationContext(), flightList.getFlight());
```

**FlightFragment.java**

```
public class FlightFragment extends ListFragment {

    private List<Flight> flight_items;

    public FlightFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        flight_items = new ArrayList<Flight>();

        //Initialise the list adapter and set
        FlightResultAdapter adapter = new FlightResultAdapter(getActivity(), flight_items);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        Flight flight = flight_items.get(position);

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), flight.getNumber(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

So what I'm not getting is how to Show the `FlightFragment` on `MyActivity`.
Furthermore how to connect it so results are displayed: I think `setListAdapter` is used?

**Update: Connecting the Fragment to the Activity**
 1. Add a FrameLayout to the activity layout, or other fragment layout

```
<FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

2. Use the FragmentManager to call the Fragment programmatically:

```
//Create the adapter here
        FlightResultAdapter adapter = new FlightResultAdapter(getApplicationContext(), flightList.getFlight());

        //Get the Fragment here and set the ListAdapter
        FlightFragment ff = new FlightFragment();
        // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an
        // Intent, pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
        ff.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

        ff.setListAdapter(adapter);

        if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {

            //Send the Data to the fragment - Need Help Here
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

            //Show the Fragment
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, ff);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
```

So the Fragment's `OnCreate` Method is being called, but the list is empty because I am not passing the `Flight` Object to the Fragment. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you adding `FlightFragment` to `MyActivity` ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK No I am not, that is what I am struggling with

Comment: see following post [How do I add a Fragment to an Activity with a programmatically created content view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159982/how-do-i-add-a-fragment-to-an-activity-with-a-programmatically-created-content-v) probably help you

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I have looked at and implemented, Thank you. How can I pass the object to the Fragment?

Comment: do you want to pass `flightList.getFlight()` List ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Yes I would like to parse the object `flightList.getFlight()` which is actually a `List<Flight>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I pass the List object to the Fragment?

Because `List` contains `Flight` custom class object. so it's not possible to pass it directly.

To pass `List<Flight>` object:

**1.** Implement `Serializable` in `Flight` class.

**2.** Use `Bundle.putSerializable` for sending object from Activity to `FlightFragment` :

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();  
bundle.putSerializable("flightList", flightList.getFlight());
ff.setArguments(bundle);
...
```

**3.** In `FlightFragment` class override `onCreateView` method and `getArguments` method:

```
@Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
            ViewGroup container, Bundle  savedInstanceState) {
  Bundle args = getArguments();
  List<Flight> flightList=(List<Flight>)args.getSerializable("flightList");
....
 return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
 }
```

Comment: Excellent, it works like a charm. Thank you. Please comment if you think there is an easier or more elegant way to do the whole task.

Comment: @StevieG: currenlty i know way which i told in my answer thanks