# Simple ListView as fragment doesn't appear

Tags: java, android, listview

I tried to add a ListView to my MainActivity, but I don't know why it doesnt appear in the App.

I created a new Layout resource file named "list_item_forecast.xml" - there I placed a TextView with the id: "list_item_forecast_textview".

In "content_main.xml" I have the ListView:

```
<ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listview_forecast" />
```

And then I have this Class in my MainActivity Class:

```
 public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment{
    ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;
    public PlaceholderFragment(){

    }
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, container,false);

        String[] forecastArray = {
                "Heute - Sonnig - 34°",
                "Morgen - Sonnig - 30°",
                "Montag - Regen - 10°",
                "Dienstag - Bewölkt - 20°",
                "Mittwoch - Schnee - 10°",
                "Donnerstag - Schnee - 15°",
                "Freitag - Sonne - 33°"
        };
        List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(forecastArray));
        mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), R.layout.list_item_forecast, R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, weekForecast);
        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(
                R.id.listview_forecast);
        listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

Here is the whole project:
https://github.com/Zaniyar/sunshine/tree/master/app/src/main

Comment: Can you add the code where the fragment is added to the activity?

Comment: eeehm how do you do that? 
This is the whole code: https://github.com/Zaniyar/sunshine/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ch/choix/sunshine/MainActivity.java

Comment: You never do anything with your new Fragment.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/28208203/2308683

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change "getContext()" to "this.getActivity()" in PlaceholderFragment.java:

```
List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(forecastArray));
    mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), R.layout.list_item_forecast, R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, weekForecast);
    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(
            R.id.listview_forecast);
    listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add your fragment to activity after you `new` it in line 41 of
your main activity ,i mean 
[this file](https://github.com/Zaniyar/sunshine/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ch/choix/sunshine/MainActivity.java)

```
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(x, "some_tag");
```

also see this links for more information

- [link 1](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/dynamically-add-fragments-to-an-activity-in-android/)
- [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5159982/4101906)

Comment: remove this line too `@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)` and try again

Comment: couldn't you checkout the project and test it? and send me your paypal adress.