# Not able to call android annotation methods in fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-annotations

I am using `Android annotation` in inflate the `Fragment`:

```
@EFragment(R.layout.fragment_sample)
public class SampleFragment extends Fragment {    
    public static SampleFragment newInstance(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        SampleFragment samplefragment = new SampleFragment_();
        return samplefragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
    }

    @AfterViews
   public void afterViewsCreated(){
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext);
  }}
```

I am invoking the instance of above fragment class from an `Activity`:

```
 SampleFragment.newInstance(getApplicationContext());
```

After enabling `debug` point in the code. Code flow is only limited to `newInstance` method. Debugger is not even going to `onActivityCreated()` , `onCreate()` and `afterViewsCreated()`. `@AfterViews` needs to be get called.

Why is this so happening?

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint inside afterViewsCreated()?

Comment: Yes, I tried it but nothing happened

Comment: Are you actually adding the fragment to your activity using the `FragmentManager`?

Comment: Errr! I am so stupid :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you appear to be doing is creating an instance of the fragment.  You don't appear to be actually calling to the FragmentManager to add()/replace() this new instance.

Try:

```
Fragment fragment = SampleFragment.newInstance(getApplicationContext());

getFragmentManager.beginTransation()
    .add(<ID RES>, fragment, <FRAGMENT TAG>)
    .commit();
```

Where ID RES is your resource id and FRAGMENT TAG is your fragment tag, if required.

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159982/how-do-i-add-a-fragment-to-an-activity-with-a-programmatically-created-content-v) for more info on using FragmentManager.