# Going from Activity to Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

So I started to work on this project that is not mine and I want to **go from an activity to a fragment**, And I tried everything that I know and found but nothing worked!

This is the class that I want go from

```
public class ConfirmBookingActivity extends BaseAppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener {
/*
some code
*/
@Override
protected void initUI() {

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_details);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    /*
     ...
    */
    setListener();

    populateData();

}
```

and this is it XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      style="@style/FillHeight.FillWidth">

  <com.example.ui.toolbar.AppToolbar
     android:id="@id/toolbar"
     style="@style/FillWidth.WrapHeight" />

  <ScrollView
     style="@style/FillHeight.FillWidth"
     android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">

     <RelativeLayout
         style="@style/FillWidth.WrapHeight"
         android:id="@+id/activity_order_details">

         <RelativeLayout...>

         </LinearLayout...>

     </RelativeLayout>
  </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is the class that I want to go to

```
public class EditProfileFragment extends BaseFragment {
/*
some code
*/
@Override
protected View initUI(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container) {
    if (mView == null) {
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_profile_edit, null);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, mView);
        setOnClickListener();

    }
    return mView;
}
```

and this is the XML for the class **EditProfileFragment**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      style="@style/FillHeight.FillWidth">

      <LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout...>

      <android.base.ui.widget.BaseTextInputLayout...>

      <android.base.ui.widget.BaseTextInputLayout...>

      <android.base.ui.widget.BaseTextView...>

      /*
        ...

      */


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: **You can't** *go from an activity to a fragment* - fragment is not a standalone and needs activity as it's host

Comment: you need to use fragment in xml and add your EditProfileFragment into it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best practice for instantiating a new Android Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new activity / fragmentactivity and attach the fragment in the new activity.

refer this : [How do I add a Fragment to an Activity with a programmatically created content view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159982/how-do-i-add-a-fragment-to-an-activity-with-a-programmatically-created-content-v)