# ListView Item Onclick to new Fragment Activity - "Unfortunately, App has stopped"

Tags: android, android-fragments, virtual-reality

Im making a `VR View` for tourist spot, In my app I have two tabs 1) the "Welcome Fragment" and 2) "ttsd". In `ttsd` fragment I put `listview` item `onclick`. Every time I choose the item which the `ttsd` calls it always crashes ("Unfortunately, Atdrag App has stopped" too) but then I try to change and put it to `Activity` it works. Below I've added my codes. I think my codes goes wrong where it calls the fragment activity.

**MainActivity** tab layout:

```
package com.example.computer.vratdragfinal;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        assert tabLayout != null;
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.welcome));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.venue));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        return new WelcomeFragment();
                    case 1:
                        return new ttsd();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 2;
            }
        };
        assert viewPager != null;
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void refreshNow() {
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(0,0);
        startActivity(getIntent());
        overridePendingTransition(0,0);

    }

}
```

**ttsd** fragment activity:

```
package com.example.computer.vratdragfinal;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.AdapterView;

public class ttsd extends Fragment {

    public ttsd() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ttsd, container, false);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        String[] awayStrings = {"Tubbataha Reef", "San Agustin Church", "Mayon Volcano", "Malapascua Island",
                "Puerto Galera", "Puerto Princesa Undergound River", "Donsol", "Banaue Rice Terraces",};

        ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView2);

        ArrayAdapter<String> lva = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, awayStrings);
        lv.setAdapter(lva);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                if(position==0) {
                    Intent myintent = new Intent(view.getContext(), toptourist1.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myintent, 0);
                }

                if(position==1) {
                    Intent myintent = new Intent(view.getContext(), toptourist2.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myintent, 1);
                }
            }
        });

        final SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_away);

        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
                new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).refreshNow();
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Refresh Layout working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
        );

        return view;
    }

}
```

**toptourist1** the fragment activity crash when i click the item in `ttsd`:

```
package com.example.computer.vratdragfinal;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.pano.VrPanoramaView;

public class toptourist1 extends Fragment {

    private VrPanoramaView panoWidgetView;
    private ImageLoaderTask backgroundImageLoaderTask;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_toptourist1, container,false);
        panoWidgetView = (VrPanoramaView) v.findViewById(R.id.pano_view);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        panoWidgetView.pauseRendering();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        panoWidgetView.resumeRendering();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        panoWidgetView.shutdown();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private synchronized void loadPanoImage() {
        ImageLoaderTask task = backgroundImageLoaderTask;
        if (task != null && !task.isCancelled()) {
            task.cancel(true);
        }

        VrPanoramaView.Options viewOptions = new VrPanoramaView.Options();
        viewOptions.inputType = VrPanoramaView.Options.TYPE_STEREO_OVER_UNDER;

        String panoImageName = "sample_converted.jpg";

        task = new ImageLoaderTask(panoWidgetView, viewOptions, panoImageName);
        task.execute(getActivity().getAssets());
        backgroundImageLoaderTask = task;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        loadPanoImage();
    }

}
```

**LogCat**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.computer.vratdragfinal, PID: 5850
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.computer.vratdragfinal/com.example.computer.vratdragfinal.toptourist1}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.computer.vratdragfinal.toptourist1 cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.computer.vratdragfinal.toptourist1 cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
Application terminated.
```

Comment: add your error logcat please.

Comment: I already wrote the logcat can you help me please.

Answer (score 1):

Look the below Logcat line:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.computer.vratdragfinal.toptourist1 cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

It's telling you that Android can't cast `toptourist1` class to `Activity` as  Android expecting a `Activity` class.

To start a `Activity` you should create a `Intent` with `Activity` class. You are creating an intent with `Fragment` class. `startActivityForResult` method is used to launch a `Activity` not Fragment.

```
  Intent myintent = new Intent(view.getContext(), toptourist2.class);
  startActivityForResult(myintent, 1);
```

Here 2nd parameter of `Intent` constructor should be a `Activity` class. If you want to use `Fragment` you have to do it with `FragmentTransaction`.

Check [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) tutorial and check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159982/how-do-i-add-a-fragment-to-an-activity-with-a-programmatically-created-content-v) question and answer.

Comment: Can you help me to solve this problem. I tried so many codes but it doesn't work I tried to remove listview item. I tried to used button or image button but the result is all the same.

Comment: Did you understand what i have written here ?

Comment: Nope Sir i don't have any idea how to make this crash.

Comment: Learn about `Fragment` and `FragmentTransaction`. I have already give you 2 links.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to call a fragment first**

```
    public void selectItem(MenuItem i){
            Fragment f = null;
            Class fClass;
```

Answer (score 0):

Toptourist1 and toptourist2 are fragments, you are opening them like activities with intents. Instead of

```
Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), toptourist1.class);
```

You should write

```
toptourist1 fragment = new toptourist1(); 
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment); // give your fragment container id in first parameter
transaction.addToBackStack(null);  // if written, this transaction will be added to backstack
transaction.commit();
```

And startActivityForResult() is used for getting data from activities not fragments. I recommend you look into the official documentation about fragments.

Comment: I can't understand what you are saying. Please read the documentation of fragments, I am sure you will get help from there.