# Error while calling Fragment class from activity

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio, location

I am currently working on an app and one of the features is to locate the nearest pharmacy. However the one of the classes PharmacyMapFragment is a Fragment class and when I try to call it, the app crashes and I get this error message:

> 'android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class
>   {com.example.junai.testapp2/com.example.junai.testapp2.PharmacyMapFragment};
>   have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?'

I thought that your not supposed to declare a Fragment class in the manifest?
I have included the code for the 3 parts that are relevant to this problem. Can someone please help with this?

Main Activity:

```
package com.example.junai.testapp2;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private Button btn_nearest_pharmacy;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn_nearest_pharmacy = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_nearest_pharmacy);


        btn_nearest_pharmacy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PharmacyMapFragment.class));
            }
        });

    }
}
```

PharmacyMapFragment Class:

```
package com.example.junai.testapp2;

import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Fragment used to display a map of the current location with the nearest pharmacies and other
 * nearby pharmacies
 *
 * References -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------/
 *  https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/tutorials/CurrentPlaceDetailsOnMap/app
 *  /src/main/java/com/example/currentplacedetailsonmap/MapsActivityCurrentPlace.java#
 *  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/current-place-tutorial
 *  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/hiding-features
 */
public class PharmacyMapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {

    //static/default values for settings
    private static final String TAG = LogTag.pharmacyLogFragment;
    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1;
    private static final int DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15;
    private static final String KEY_CAMERA_POSITION = "camera_position";
    private static final String KEY_LOCATION = "location";
    private final LatLng mDefaultLocation = new LatLng(56.463190, -3.038596 );

    //used objects
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private CameraPosition mCameraPosition;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private boolean mLocationPermissionGranted;
    private Location mLastKnownLocation;

    private ArrayList<Pharmacy> pharmacies = new ArrayList<>();

    public PharmacyMapFragment() {}

    @Override //generates layout
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pharmacy_map, container, false);
    }

    @Override //setup method
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //used for smoother transitions if this is not the first state
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mLastKnownLocation = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_LOCATION);
            mCameraPosition = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_CAMERA_POSITION);
        }

        //set up api client for api calls
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .enableAutoManage((FragmentActivity) getActivity(), this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        mMap = map;

        updateLocationUI(); //updates the UI, called first in case of previous sessions
        getDeviceLocation(); //get current device location
        getPharmaciesFromAPI(); //gets pharmacies from google places search api

    }

    //Used to update the UI
    private void updateLocationUI() {
        if (mMap == null) {  //if map is null exit method
            return;
        }

        //if we have locations permission set permission to true
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }

        //if we have location permissions update the ui
        if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        } else {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
            mLastKnownLocation = null;
        }
    }

    private void getDeviceLocation() {
        //Get location permissions and try to locate current position
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }

        if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
            mLastKnownLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                    .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        }

        // Set the map's camera position to the current location of the device.
        if (mCameraPosition != null) {
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(mCameraPosition));
        } else if (mLastKnownLocation != null) {
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(),
                            mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cannot get location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(TAG, "Current location is null. Using defaults.");
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mDefaultLocation, DEFAULT_ZOOM));
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    @Override //used when the premission result comes back
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[],
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
                }
            }
        }
        updateLocationUI();
    }

    //gets list of pharmacies as a json object from the api
    public void getPharmaciesFromAPI(){
        double lat,lng;

        if(mLastKnownLocation != null) {
            lat = mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude();
            lng = mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude();
        } else {
            lat = mDefaultLocation.latitude;
            lng = mDefaultLocation.longitude;
        }

        // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        String API_KEY = getString(R.string.API_KEY);
        String url ="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?"
                + "location=" + lat + "," + lng + "&rankby=distance&type=pharmacy&key=" + API_KEY;

        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        parseJSON(response); //parse the json response into pharmacy objects
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d(TAG, error.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cannot connect to the internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        });
        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(jsObjRequest);
    }

    //parses the json
    private void parseJSON(JSONObject response){
        try {
            JSONArray results = response.getJSONArray("results");
            pharmacies.clear();

            for(int i=0; i<results.length();i++) {
                Pharmacy pharmacy = new Pharmacy();
                JSONObject current = results.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject location = current.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location");

                pharmacy.setLat(location.getDouble("lat"));
                pharmacy.setLng(location.getDouble("lng"));
                pharmacy.setName(current.getString("name"));
                pharmacy.setInfo(current.getString("vicinity"));
                pharmacies.add(pharmacy);
            }
            addMapMarkers(pharmacies);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
        }
    }

    //adds markers for pharmacies onto the map
    private void addMapMarkers(ArrayList<Pharmacy> pharmacies) {
        for(int i=0;i<pharmacies.size();i++) {
            double lat = pharmacies.get(i).getLat();
            double lng = pharmacies.get(i).getLng();
            String title = pharmacies.get(i).getName();

            if(i==0) {
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat,lng)).title(title)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.
                                HUE_AZURE)));
            } else {
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat,lng)).title(title));
            }
        }
        showDialog(pharmacies.get(0));
    }

    private void showDialog(Pharmacy pharmacy) {
        // Supply num input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("name", pharmacy.getName());
        args.putString("info", pharmacy.getInfo());

        DialogFragment nearestPharmacy = new NearestPharmacyFragment();
        nearestPharmacy.setArguments(args);
        nearestPharmacy.show(getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(), "dialog");
    }

    /*
    *  API and connection call methods
    */
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        if (mMap != null) {
            outState.putParcelable(KEY_CAMERA_POSITION, mMap.getCameraPosition());
            outState.putParcelable(KEY_LOCATION, mLastKnownLocation);
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        }
    }

    @Override // Build the map.
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        MapFragment fragment = new MapFragment();
        transaction.add(R.id.map, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
        fragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Play services connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "
                + result.getErrorCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Play services connection suspended. Error code: " + cause);
    }

}
```

fragment_pharmacy_map.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.junai.testapp2.PharmacyMapFragment"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" >

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.junai.testapp2">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <user-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="TestApp2"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAFK4WLnnx-G4RIV5-3wr2-Pp5LnrkmQhw" />


        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
<activity
    android:name=".Test">
</activity>

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Intent`s are meant to start a new *`activity`* but you are using that to start a *`Fragment`*, So that is the error.

But Don't worry, not a big deal.

In **MainActivity.java**,

Replace this code

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PharmacyMapFragment.class));
```

with this one

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new PharmacyMapFragment()).commit();
```

Make sure that the `auto-import` is enabled.

This will do the trick.

Comment: I did that and I got this error:                                                                              Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'com.example.junai.testapp2.PharmacyMapFragment', required: 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' less... 

replace
(int,
android.support.v4.app.Fragment)
in FragmentTransaction cannot be applied
to
(int,
com.example.junai.testapp2.PharmacyMapFragment)

Comment: Firstly, why your MainActivity is extending to FragmentActivity..!!  Change that to `AppCompatActivity`. Remember to import this too....                    And secondly in your PharmacyMapFragment, remove this line `import android.app.Fragment;` and add this line `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`

Comment: I decided to change the fragment class into an activity and then it worked but thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 2):

An activity can be represented as a single screen and a fragment as a subview inside that.

You cannot directly show a fragment, you need a host to attach it on, that is, you need an activity which will host your fragment. You can put single or multiple fragments in an activity and the fragments will be shown in that.

Here you called startActivity, this method is used to launch an activity, you passed a PharmacyMapFragment,it is a fragment and not an activity.  Thereby, it failed to look a activity with that type and threw that error.

TL;DR

Create a activity, put the PharmacyMapFragment inside it, by placing it in the activity's layout or using Fragment transaction and then call startActivity with the class name of that activity

Tutorial: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding

Answer (score 1):

Dude you are trying to start fragment as an Activity by using intent. That is wrong. You should use FragmentManager as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159982/how-do-i-add-a-fragment-to-an-activity-with-a-programmatically-created-content-v).