# How to pass the data fragment to other fragment activity in android studio

Tags: android

SectionFragment.class

```
Intent subjectDetail = new Intent(getContext(), GradeFragment.class);
        ListGradeData clickItem = sectionList.get(position);

        subjectDetail.putExtra(EXTRA_SECTION_ID, String.valueOf(clickItem.getSectionId()));
        startActivity(subjectDetail);
```

GradeFragment.class

```
String studSectionId = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString(EXTRA_SECTION_ID);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), studSectionId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

it doesn't display the studentSectionId. When I run the app it always crashed after I click the button

Comment: `GradeFragment`  is a fragment or Activity?

Comment: use to need FragmentManager class to push fragment, fragment don't start with startActivity(),

Comment: Have you already searched the internet how to do this?

Comment: @Sarath its fragment also

Comment: @ZUNJAE i already searched sir. But I'll try more sir.

Comment: _Fragment also_?  What does it mean? My question was, Are you trying to launch a fragment or Activity?

Comment: @Sarath.... I have here main activity. so I have tabbed 3 fragments and the sectionfragments.class have recyclerview. I was trying to do now is when I click the recyclerview item it should get the value of the recyclerview item that I was clicked.

Comment: Your activity has 3 fragments and you are trying to pass data from one fragment to another?

Comment: @Sarath yes. ..

Comment: @NewbieCoder Have a look into this https://www.journaldev.com/14207/android-passing-data-between-fragments

Answer (score 0):

For fragment use FragmentManager to add/replace fragments. and create send data like

```
MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();

Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt("someInt", someInt);
myFragment.setArguments(args);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159982/how-do-i-add-a-fragment-to-an-activity-with-a-programmatically-created-content-v